# How can I create a layout like the one in the image?

Tags: android, layout

I want to have something like this image [image]
But when the texts are not equal in length the distance between TextViews are changeing and when it's too much words go to next line.

[image]

the xml code for layout that I have created is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
        
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" >
                <TextView
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical |right"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/shape_rectangle"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"                    
                    android:layout_weight="33.66"
                    android:text=" text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical |right"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/shape_rectangle"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"                    
                    android:layout_weight="33.66"
                    android:text="some text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

                <TextView
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                   android:gravity="center_vertical |right"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/shape_rectangle"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"                    
                    android:layout_weight="33.66"
                   android:text="some text with more word"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        
            </LinearLayout>

            <View        
                android:background="#CCC"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I have a layout with steady look with diffrence text and on all screen size ?

Comment: It looks like you want a grid layout with auto or star column widths (play around with it, though note that auto requires more calculation).

Comment: thanks, @RobotHead could you please show me an example of a grid layout with equal column width?

Comment: If you want three equal columns in a grid you can set the widths of the column definitions to "33.33*". Note the asterisk. Then you shouldn't have to set any width or horizontal layout parameters on the textviews at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set  `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to all your `TextViews`, also if all the weights are the same you can set 1 to everyone, it's the ratio that matters, not the number itself.

```
<TextView
            ...
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
```

Edit: Adding **android:singleLine** and **android:singleLineattribute** to the answer to match the question criteria.

Comment: nope, their height is already is set to match_parent and changing the weight to 1 didn't work.

Comment: I edit your answer to match the question demand.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch to a ConstraintLayout and create an horizontal chain (https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain)